# Case insensitive \setkeys in xkeyval

Tags: xkeyval

I'm trying to figure out how to make the usebib package case-insensitive on the keys in my .bib file.  I've figured out how to patch `\KV@split` to patch `\KV@@sp@def` when `\setkeys` is defined by `keyval` rather than `xkeyval`:

```
\let\KV@@sp@def@orig=\KV@@sp@def
\def\KV@@casenormalize{%
  \long\def\KV@@sp@def##1##2{\lowercase{\KV@@sp@def@orig{##1}{##2}}\let\KV@@sp@def=\KV@@sp@def@orig}%
}
\pretocmd{\KV@split}{\KV@@casenormalize}{}{%
    \PackageWarning{usebib}
    {Unpatchable command \string\KV@split. Fields will be case-sensitive.}
    {The version of the keyval package does not have a definition of \string\KV@split\space that is compatible with patching for case normalization.}
}%
```

So, for example, this works and produces `Foo` as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{usebib}
\newbibfield{author}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@misc{foo,
  Author = {Foo}
}
\end{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\let\KV@@sp@def@orig=\KV@@sp@def
\def\KV@@casenormalize{%
  \long\def\KV@@sp@def##1##2{\lowercase{\KV@@sp@def@orig{##1}{##2}}\let\KV@@sp@def=\KV@@sp@def@orig}%
}
\pretocmd{\KV@split}{\KV@@casenormalize}{}{%
  \PackageWarning{usebib}
                 {Unpatchable command \string\KV@split. Fields will be case-sensitive.}
                 {The version of the keyval package does not have a definition of \string\KV@split\space that is compatible with patching for case normalization.}
}%
\makeatother
\bibinput{foo}
\begin{document}
\usebibentry{foo}{author}
\end{document}
```

However, if I load `xkeyval` at the beginning, then I get `` Package usebib Error: Undefined key `foo' or empty value for `author'. `` because `xkeyval` does not use `\KV@split`.  How do I make this work even when using `xkeyval`?  (And/or is there a better way to do this?)